# Php script to javascript

Tags: php, javascript, scripting

I am trying to write something similar in javascript

```
function Spin($txt){

$test = preg_match_all("#\{(.*?)\}#", $txt, $out);

if (!$test) return $txt;

$toFind = Array();
$toReplace = Array();

foreach($out[0] AS $id => $match){
$choices = explode(”|”, $out[1][$id]);
$toFind[]=$match;
$toReplace[]=trim($choices[rand(0, count($choices)-1)]);
}

return str_replace($toFind, $toReplace, $txt);
```

But not sure where to start - If there is anybody out there that can help me, please help!

I have a the following as input:

{keyword 1 | keyword 2 | keyword 3} {word 1 | word 2 | word 3} {test 1, test 2, test 3}

The purpose of the script is to combine

- [Keyword 1] [word 1] [test 1]
- [keyword 2] [and word 2] [test 2]
- [keyword 3] [and word 3] [test 3]

I am not sure how to create a array to take the first string { string 1 } break it where ever there is a | then take string 2 { string 2 } and break it at the | and {string 3} and break it at |

and then to combine the strings...

Comment: please explain what the function is supposed to do and what your problem is. Have you tried anything so far?

Comment: Rather than just dumping the code and expecting someone to do all the work you could at least outline what you're attempting to achieve - especially as your code isn't even commented.

Answer (score 1):

Neither input nor output make sense to me, but well, this should push you into the right direction:

```
var input = '{keyword 1 | keyword 2 | keyword 3} {word 1 | word 2 | word 3} {test 1, test 2, test 3}';
var matches = input.match(/\{(.*?)\}/ig); // grab stuff in curly braces
var choices = matches[0].replace('{', '') // remove left curly brace
                        .replace('}', '') // remove right curly brace
                        .split(' | ');    // split into array
```

`choices` will then be an array

```
['keyword 1', 'keyword 2', 'keyword 3']
```

You could do the same for words and tests and can then combine these as you see fit.

Answer (score 0):

Look for split method on string

and join method on arrays

Search for Javascript split and Javascript join (separate queries) in google. The w3schools links are quite useful

Comment: Thanks Amit ;-) will try it now - and will let you know of the progress